# Can you pass a "type" as an argument?

Tags: vb.net, casting, types

I want to do something like the following in VB.NET, is it possible?

```
Function task(value as Object, toType as Type)

   Return DirectCast(value, toType)

End Function
```

Comment: Why don't you cast your object *before* sending it to the Task function?

Comment: Isn't that an obvious workaround?!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. There is System.Type. You may actually want to do a Generic however.

```
Function SomeFunction(Of T)(obj As Object) As T
    '' Magic
End Function
```

Comment: Oh doh. I'm so used to C# these days.

Comment: @Ama whatever you want to do.

Comment: I do not understand what your function does: what it is supposed to return, and how do I specify T. I tried Fredou's sugestion which is to `return obj`, but yet I can't even use the function. I get a "Type parameter 'T' cannot be inferred."

Comment: @Ama - see my answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63427203/9792594), hopefully that explains how to call a generic function?

Answer (score 4):

Great Answer - Here is a generic function to do the same:

```
Public Sub BindListControlToEnum(Of T)(ListCtrl As ListControl)
    Dim itemValues As Array = System.Enum.GetValues(GetType(T))
    Dim itemNames As Array = System.Enum.GetNames(GetType(T))
    For i As Integer = 0 To itemNames.Length - 1
        Dim item As New ListItem(itemNames(i), itemValues(i))
        ListCtrl.Items.Add(item)
    Next
End Sub
```

Call it like this:

```
BindDropdownToEnum(Of MyClass.MyEnum)(MyRadioButtonListControl)
```

Answer (score 3):

you want to use the

```
function task(of myType)(value as myType) as MyType
   ''stuff
   return value
end function
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar today (essentially filling in the `'' magic` from the accepted answer):

```vb
Private Function Convert_Value_Or_Fallback(Of T)(ByRef value As Object, ByRef fallback As Object) As Object
    Try
        Return DirectCast(value, T)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return fallback
    End Try
End Function

'call it like this:'
Convert_Value_Or_Fallback(Of Double)(value, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, though, depending on your requirements, you may want to use CType to do any type casting/conversion. CType will work so long as there is a valid type conversion, whereas DirectCast requires that `value` be of the type `toType`.