# Cast an Exception into a NonGenericException according to a Type variable

Tags: vb.net

I would like to throw a `System.Exception` of a given `Type`, such `Type` being passed as an argument of the `Sub` which `Throw`s the `Exception`.

Then I would call the `Sub` like this: `Call ThrowEvent("Wrong format: MyString must comply with the following pattern ***, System.FormatException)`

So far I came up with this, but `DirectCast` is not happy:

> ExceptionType is not defined

```
Public Shared Sub ThrowEvent(ByVal Message As String, ByVal ExceptionType As Type)

    Dim MyException As New System.Exception(Message)
    MyException = DirectCast(MyException, ExceptionType)
    Throw MyException

End Sub
```

I have never used DirectCast for anything othger than  Interfaces (usually when playing around with Collections)

I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f7362ba9-48cd-49eb-9c65-d91355a3daee/explicit-conversion-of-base-class-to-derived-class?forum=csharplanguage) but did not really understand the full picture..

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074251/can-you-pass-a-type-as-an-argument), but I do not understand how I am supposed to us the `(Of T)`

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't make sense for numerous reasons, not least of which is the fact that, if you were to get it to work, you would see that method at the top of the stack trace every time you threw an exception.  You can't really do what you're trying to do and nor should you even try, so give up on the idea.  Wherever you think you want to call that method, just create the actual type of exception you want to throw and throw it, just like everyone else does.

Comment: You also ought to do some reading on what a `Type` object is and how it is not a data type, as well as what casting actually is.  Have you ever heard the expression "to cast something in a different light"? That basically means to look at the same thing in a different way. That's how casting works in programming. It doesn't change an object in any way. It simply accesses that object via a reference of a different type. You can't cast something as a type that it isn't already. You can cast a `FormatException` as type `Exception` but you can't cast an `Exception` as type `FormatException`.

Comment: Ok for the casting, now I understand why it works well with Interfaces.

Comment: Basically my ThrowEvent function includes other things, such as Event Logging. I would like to have all my logging routines in one place so that maintenance is easy. I don't mind having the trace going up to that last function, I'll just know the error was thrown from the level just below; right?

Comment: This has got nothing to do with events. Exceptions and events are two completely different things. If you want a method to log exceptions then write a method to log exceptions. There's no reason for that method to throw the exception. What you're trying to do is wrong. If you want to do the wrong thing then that is your prerogative but I will not be helping you do so.

Comment: You could also use your Exception type as the InnerException of the new Exception. It can be set in the contructor.

Comment: More than happy to change my approach if recommended. So my function checks the type of exception Thrown, and depending on it it will log or not log an event, and it will pop or not pop a MsgBox to the user. I may in the future decide to log an Exception I did not log before. Having everything centralised helps in that sense. WHere can I get some reading on how to properly handle this?

Comment: See the *Implementing custom exceptions* section of the [Exception class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception)

Comment: Thank you Jimi for an excellent link! I know what an InnException is (and actually until I read your link I did not know you could just `Throw;` instead of encapsulating Exceptions), but I am not sure how this responds to my question?

Comment: @Jimi wrapping exceptions instead of rethrowing can be actively hostile to debugging.  I will routinely turn up the break-on-throw in the exception settings, and in a module that does a lot of wrap-and-rethrow, I'll end up having to hit continue about 20 times any time an exception issues at a low-ish level in the module.  I'm not saying to never do it, but think carefully about the design and how it may interact with future development work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comments already discussed, this is not good idea at all. The concept is generally wrong and the exceptin will mess your code anyway. You should do some Try/Catch with general handling instead.

But if you really want to wrap your "throw" to "log and throw", than the easiest was is this:

```
Public Shared Sub ProcessThrow(Ex As Exception)
    'Do your logging here
    Throw Ex
End Sub
```

and call it like

```
ProcessThrow(New FormatException("Wrong format: MyString must comply with the following pattern ***""))
```

Better way of doing this is

```
Public Shared Sub HandleEx(Ex As Exception)
    'Do your logging here
End Sub
```

and call it like this

```
Try
    'Do something
    Throw New FormatException("Wrong format: MyString must comply with the following pattern ***")
Catch ex As Exception
    HandleEx(ex)
    'Recover
End Try
```

Comment: Thanks Pavlinll. That is what I was doing so far, but because sometimes I log without throwin an error, then the MyException argument is opptionnal, but then I cannot retrieve the .Message which I use in the EventLog. Hence me trying to pass the Exception Type rather than an instance.

Comment: So it is good practice to have the EventLog capturing within the `Catch`? One other reason I had this LogAndThrow() was because in addition to Throwing an erro, I wanted to provide a category of Exception as well as the Exception (Category provided through a Global variable, set through the LogAndThrow). Anyways, now I have some reading and research to do so that I can come up with something cleaner.

Comment: You can use HandleEx(Message As String) for your Do-Not-Throw situation and call it directly. I usually use HandleEx(Ex As Exception, Optional Description As String=Nothing) to handle extra stuff. I'm not sure what you mean by "Category" of exception. Is it ex.GetType.Name?

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is not recommended and I will not implement this solution, however for completeness and to help understand how Generic functions work, here are two solutions:

## .Message not needed

```
Public Shared Sub ThrowEvent(Of TException As {System.Exception, New})()

    Throw New TException() 'Passing arguments to the creator is not permited

End Sub
```

## .Message needed

```
Public Shared Sub ThrowEvent(Of TException As {System.Exception})(ByVal MyMessage As String)

    Dim MyException As TException = Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(TException), New Object() {MyMessage})
    Throw MyException

End Sub
```

Again, this answers the question, but the question seeks a strategy which is not recommended.